Is there an integral formula for the square root of the Gamma function?
What I've Tried:

We have that if $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t_{1}}f(x,t_{1})e^{-t_{2}}f(x,t_{2})dt_{1}dt_{2}=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt$, in order to make the LHS look like the RHS, we can use the change of variables $t=t_{1}+t_{2}, t_{1}=t_{1}$ so that the integral becomes $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}\int_{0}^{t}f(x,t_{1})f(x,t-t_{1})dt_{1}dt$. To make the two integrals equal, we'd like the convolution to be $t^{x}$, though it does not have to be. We use the fact $\mathcal{L}\{f_{1}\star f_{2}\}=\mathcal{L}\{f_{1}\}\mathcal{L}\{f_{2}\}$, where $\star$ denotes convolution, to find a solution for $f(x)$. $\mathcal{L}\{t^{x-1}\}=\frac{\Gamma(x)}{s^{x}}$ so that we have $\mathcal{L}\{f(x,t)\}=\frac{\sqrt{\Gamma(x)}}{s^{\frac{x}{2}}}$, and $f(x,t)=\frac{t^{\frac{x-2}{2}}\sqrt{\Gamma(x)}}{\Gamma(\frac{x}{2})}$. However, evaluating $\sqrt{\Gamma(x)}=\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{\Gamma(x)}}{\Gamma(\frac{x}{2})}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{\frac{x-2}{2}}dt,$ one obtains a circular definition.

Context:

One of my friends asked me if there were any positive integer solutions to $m!=n^{2}-1$ other than $(4,5)$, $(5,11)$, and $(7,71)$. In other words, he asked me Brocard's Problem. Using $\displaystyle\sqrt{x-2}<\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}}<\sqrt{x-1}$, I reasoned that it was equivalent to the following: if $A(m)=\lceil\sqrt{m!}\rceil$, then for m>7, $A(m)-\sqrt{m!}>\frac{1}{2\sqrt{m!}}$. This may be easier to prove if we find integral representations of $\sqrt{m!}=\sqrt{\Gamma(m+1)}$ and $A(m)$.
